# How to update location from background in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I am making an application in which i need to update the location from background when user presses the home button, i have already added in the info.plist in UIBackGroundModes for updateuserlocation, please let me know apart from this anything else is there that have to me do, like have to start location manager for updating please help me

Comment: I don't think you can tie a location update to a user action while in the background. Your app just gets the updates as they come...(normal, significant changes, or region monitor)...you can put a system in place to ignore most, but don't think you can start while in the background

Comment: Oh, or did you just mean 'begin background updating when the user leaves the app?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a `CLLocationManager` and call `startUpdatingLocation` from within the App Delegate `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

However, this will cause a major drain on the battery & isn't recommended. Instead, you should probably use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to keep the location checking at a minimum.